# Salvar conteúdo de uma Listbox no banco de dados mysql

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, tkinter

Bom dia,

Eu tenho um listbox e estou com dificuldaldes de armazenar o conteúdo  dessa lista no banco de dados Mysql. Alguém poderia me ajudar. Segui codigo e erro abaixo:

```
    def SaveVariosCodBr(self):
    db=self.conexaoBanco()
    cursor=db.cursor()
    listcod = self.ListCodBrGer.get(ALL)
    sql="insert into "+self.entrPsCodBr.get()+"(codigo,situacao)values('"+listcod+"','ativo')"
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
        print('Dados Gravados')
    except MySQLdb as erro:
        print('Nao conseguiu Gravar')
    db.close()
```

esse é o erro que da:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2619, in get
return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', first)
TclError: bad listbox index "all": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number
```

Comment: formatar como ?

Comment: e que essse é parte do codigo

Answer (score 0):

Diunior, em minha opnião o erro esta ocorrendo aqui :

```
listcod = self.ListCodBrGer.get(ALL)
```

deveria estar assim :

```
listcod = self.ListCodBr.get(0, END)
```

como não entendo muito de mysql não consigo te dizer se na hora de inserir o conteudo dentro do banco de dados está correto.